# Can't find Databasehelper from AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

Currently, I'm trying to insert data into an SQLite database. I already achieved that. But now I'm probably having a context problem.

Once I press the button an AlertDialog is opening. After that, you can put text into an EditText. Now the user has to press ok and after that, the date from that EditText needs to go into the SQLite database.

The Problem is "DataBaseHelper_DB DataBaseHelper_DB = new DataBaseHelper_DB(getActivity());" is always null.

How can I change this?

```
 private void openDialog() {
    Dialog Dialog = new Dialog();
    Dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialog");
}

__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

public class Dialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment 
{
private EditText Profile;
Date date;
DpD_DB DpD_DB;

DataBaseHelper_DB DataBaseHelper_DB = new DataBaseHelper_DB(getActivity()); 



@Override
public android.app.Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);



    builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("Profile")
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String editProfile = Profile.getText().toString();

                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                    SimpleDateFormat sdfT = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
                    date = new Date();

                    try {
                        DpD_DB = new DpD_DB(-1, sdf.format(date).toString(), 
                        sdfT.format(date).toString(), editProfile);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.toString();
                    }

                    DataBaseHelper_DB.addOne(DpD_DB);

                }
            });
    Profile = view.findViewById(R.id.Profile);

    return builder.create();
}

________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

public DataBaseHelper_DB(@Nullable Context Context){
    super(Context, DB_TABLE, null, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing a listener for your Dialogs like the code below. in your Activity class, implement the listener and use the listeners method to get the text. Hope i am clear.

```
public class Dialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment{

private EditText Profile;
Date date;
DpD_DB DpD_DB;
ProjectDialogListener listener;

DataBaseHelper_DB DataBaseHelper_DB = new DataBaseHelper_DB(getActivity()); 



@Override
public android.app.Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);



    builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("Profile")
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String editProfile = Profile.getText().toString();

                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                    SimpleDateFormat sdfT = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
                    date = new Date();

                    try {
                        DpD_DB = new DpD_DB(-1, sdf.format(date).toString(), 
                        sdfT.format(date).toString(), editProfile);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.toString();
                    }

                    //DataBaseHelper_DB.addOne(DpD_DB);
                    //Use the listener to get the text
                    listener.applyTexts(Dpd_DB)
                }
            });
    Profile = view.findViewById(R.id.Profile);

    return builder.create();
}



 @Override
  public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
      listener = (ProjectDialogListener) getActivity();//I am guessing u are using an activity else your the getActivity to getTargetFragment.
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
      throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + "must implement ProjectDialogListener");
    }
  }

public interface ProjectDialogListener {
    void applyTexts(String title);
  }
```

Comment: Now the dialog isn't even opening anymore. But your idea made me think about a different solution which solved the Problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Gibby_Gibbson glad to help